# Should socket.io server update the database?

Tags: socket.io

I’m bulilding a web app that requires communication between clients. For this I’m using socket.io. Some data however has to be updated regularly in the database.

Some of them not that often (preferences, on button click) others in every second for example a timer value. This can not be calculated because the timer can be paused.

Right now whenever a client emits an event, it also makes a request to the backend to updated the database. I was wondering if it would be a good idea to have the socket.io server update the database so the clients would only have to take care of the socket communication? It seems to me that having the browser do a request to the backend is a bit resource heavy and takes out a bit from the advantages of the socket based communication

**Edit:** the back end of the app and the socket server are two different servers but physically they are on the same machine so their communication could be faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main point of using socket.io is that it allows you to push data to clients and clients do not need to check your server constantly to get the last changes, and providing a low-overhead communication channel between the server and the client.
you can call an API and also emit data and many other things on user click in your application.
it is a good idea to have the socket.io server update the database and you can also authorize each socket, save client sockets information and ...